# How to decode tagged union types in Elm?

Tags: json, elm, decoder

If I have a certain tagged union type, like `Shape` here, how would I construct a JSON decoder for it in Elm?

```
type alias Rectangle = { width : Int, height : Int }

type alias Circle = { radius: Int }

type Shape 
    = ShapeRectangle Rectangle 
    | ShapeCircle Circle
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given your JSON looks like

`{ "radius" : 10 }`

or

`{ "width" : 20, "height" : 15}`

Then this will do the trick

```
import Json.Decode as Json exposing ((:=))

decodeShape : Json.Decoder Shape
decodeShape =
  Json.oneOf
    [ decodeShapeRectangle
    , decodeShapeCircle
    ]

decodeShapeRectangle : Json.Decoder Shape
decodeShapeRectangle =
  Json.map ShapeRectangle <|
    Json.object2 Rectangle
       ("width" := Json.int)
       ("height" := Json.int)


decodeShapeCircle : Json.Decoder Shape
decodeShapeCircle =
    Json.object1 (ShapeCircle << Circle)
         ("radius" := Json.int)
```

A couple of additional things: I often add a 'type' and 'tag' field to help disambiguate when I have data types with common field names. The JSON then looks like

`{ "type":"shape", "tag":"circle", "radius":10 }`

Also, I think `:=` will be replaced by `field` in the upcoming 0.18 release.

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 4):

Michel Thoma's answer shone a great light here.

You can tag decoded values using `Json.Decode.map` or `andThen` like this:

```
`andThen` \x -> decode (MyTag x)
```

Using here is a solution using `andThen` and Json.Decode.Pipeline

```
import Json.Decode exposing ( Decoder, decodeString, int, andThen, oneOf )
import Json.Decode.Pipeline exposing ( decode, required )

import Html

main =
  let
    decoded = decodeString decodeShape "{ \"radius\": 2 }"
   in
     case decoded of
       Ok shape ->
         Html.text <| toString shape

       Err error ->
         Html.text error

type alias Rectangle = { width : Int, height : Int }

type alias Circle = { radius: Int }

type Shape
    = ShapeRectangle Rectangle
    | ShapeCircle Circle



decodeShape : Decoder Shape
decodeShape =
  oneOf
    [ decodeRectangle `andThen` \x -> decode (ShapeRectangle x)
    , decodeCircle `andThen` \x -> decode (ShapeCircle x)
    ]



decodeRectangle : Decoder Rectangle
decodeRectangle =
    decode Rectangle
        |> required "width" int
        |> required "height" int




decodeCircle : Decoder Circle
decodeCircle =
    decode Circle
         |> required "radius" int
```