# How to a decode Json.Decode.Value into tagged union type in elm 0.19?

Tags: json, functional-programming, elm, decoder

I see

- [How to decode tagged union types in Elm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193642/how-to-decode-tagged-union-types-in-elm)
- [Elm JSON decoder for Union type with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758453/elm-json-decoder-for-union-type-with-data?rq=1)

I don't believe the first is relevant for elm 0.19. I could not find a `decode` function in [NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline/1.0.0/) and I do not believe the `:=` infix operator is still valid.

The second addresses the slightly different question of conditionally decoding based on the value of a JSON field.

If I have data coming over a port and the following types:

import Json.Decode exposing (Decoder, map, oneOf, string, succeed, andThen, map2, map4)

```
import Json.Decode exposing (Decoder, andThen, map, map2, map4, oneOf, string, succeed, field)


port loginResponse : (Value -> msg) -> Sub msg


type Status
    = Authenticated Data
    | Unauthenticated (Maybe Error)


type alias Data =
    { accessToken : String
    , email : String
    , name : String
    , nickname : String
    }


dataDecoder : Decoder Data
dataDecoder =
    map4 Data
        (field "accessToken" string)
        (field "email" string)
        (field "name" string)
        (field "nickname" string)


type alias Error =
    { error : String
    , errorDescription : String
    }


errorDecoder : Decoder Error
errorDecoder =
    map2 Error
        (field "error" string)
        (field "errorDescription" string)
```

How can I write a decoder for tagged union type `Status` to decode the data coming back in from the port?

Best I got so far is something like

```
statusDecoder : Decoder Status
statusDecoder =
    oneOf
        [ dataDecoder andThen (\data -> succeed (Authenticated data)
        , errorDecoder andThen (\error -> succeed (Unauthenticated (Just error)))
        ]
```

which isn't valid, or

```
getStatus : Json.Decode.Value -> Status
getStatus value =
    let
        decodedData =
            decodeValue dataDecoder value
    in
    case decodedData of
        Ok data ->
            Authenticated data

        Err _ ->
            let
                decodedError =
                    decodeValue errorDecoder value
            in
            case decodedError of
                Ok error ->
                    Unauthenticated (Just error)

                Err err ->
                    Unauthenticated (Just { error = "There was a problem decoding the JSON", errorDescription = "" })
```

which is really ugly and doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've done all the hard work. This should be all you need now. Note `.map` is the quick way to do your case statement stuff.

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)
statusDecoder =
    Decode.oneOf
        [ Decode.map Authenticated dataDecoder
        , Decode.map Unauthenticated <| Decode.maybe errorDecoder
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I went with is to use [Json.Decode.map](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode) to translate the `Decoder Data` and `Decoder Error` types to `Decoder Status` types using the `Status` type constructors `Authenticated data` and `Unauthenticated Maybe error`.

I can then use the [Json.Decode.oneOf](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode) function to decode into one or the other depending on the shape of the data because both decoders are now of the same type `Decoder Status`.

```
dataDecoder : Decoder Status
dataDecoder =
    map Authenticated <|
        map4 Data
            (field "accessToken" string)
            (field "email" string)
            (field "name" string)
            (field "nickname" string)


errorDecoder : Decoder Status
errorDecoder =
    map Unauthenticated <|
        maybe <|
            map2 Error
                (field "error" string)
                (field "errorDescription" string)


statusDecoder : Decoder Status
statusDecoder =
    oneOf [ dataDecoder, errorDecoder ]
```

For brevity you can then use the [Json.Decode.decodeValue](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode) function with the `statusDecoder` function defined above to decode the `Json.Decode.Value` coming out of the port in your update function.

```
-- UPDATE

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ReceiveLoginResponse response ->
            let
                decodedResponse = decodeValue Auth.statusDecoder response
            in
            case decodedResponse of
                Ok status ->
                    ( { model
                        | authStatus = status 
                      }
                      , Cmd.none
                    )
         ...

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ loginResponse ReceiveLoginResponse
        ]
```