# How to Encode and Decode Simple Custom Types in Elm?

Tags: json, elm, custom-type

In Elm, there's no native way to encode/decode a custom type. This makes send and receive custom-typed values to JS difficult. I was confused for a while and wonder how to handle simple custom types like the one below?

```
type MyCustomType
  = A
  | B
  | C
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244984/how-to-a-decode-json-decode-value-into-tagged-union-type-in-elm-0-19 I think this is a duplicate of that question, but this question is formulated a lot more generally

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick and simple demo of how to encode and decode any custom types.

Say you have a custom type like this:

```
type MyCustomType
  = A
  | B
  | C
```

You can encode `MyCustomType` directly as a string:

```
encodeMyCustomType : MyCustomType -> Encode.Value
encodeMyCustomType myCustomType =
  Encode.string <|
    case myCustomType of
      A -> "A"
      B -> "B"
      C -> "C"
```

Decoding `MyCustomType` is slightly more involved. You need to use [`Decode.andThen`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#andThen) to check which variant is found and use [`Decode.fail`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#fail) in case no valid variant is found:

```
Decode.string |>
  Decode.andThen
    (\str ->
      case str of
        "A" -> Decode.succeed A
        "B" -> Decode.succeed B
        "C" -> Decode.succeed C
        _ -> Decode.fail "Invalid MyCustomType"
    )
```